# jQuery check click for each link

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#showKey").each(
    $(this).click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("value"));
    })
);
```

And

```
<a id="showKey" href="#" value="{{ customer.key }}">
   <span class="icons icon-key"></span>
   Show key
</a>
```

The alert gives and undefined output, just 'undefined'. I have a list of customers and a click on #showKey should reveal the key for the clicked customer.

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Why do you use `each` on id selector? do you have multiple elements with the same id? **It's an invalid HTML!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID - use a class instead. Additionally, you don't need the call to .each -- use a class selector instead:

```
$(".showKey").click(function(){
     alert($(this).data("key"));
);

<a class="showKey" href="#" data-key="{{ customer.key }}">Show key</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `data` attribute:

```
<a id="showKey" href="#" data-value="{{ customer.key }}">
   <span class="icons icon-key"></span>
   Show key
</a>


$("#showKey").click(function(){
    alert($(this).data("value"));
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LKArX/

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the [jQuery each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function.

```
$("#showKey").click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr("value"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is in your usage of

```
$("#showkey").each({...});
```

You should simply use

```
$("#showkey").click({function(){
   alert( $this).val() );
   }
});
```

to bind the click event to every showkey id'd element.